# Web service for live Forex data for Eastern Europe currency?

Tags: web-services, data-processing, forex

Is there a Web service for live Forex data for Eastern Europe currency? The yahoo data is updated with a couple of minutes delay, so I don't want to use that. I've seen some Java Applets, but thy are no use, as I can't extract any data from them.

As a specific request I'm looking for quotes on the Romanian currency, RON.

Answer (score 1):

[XE.com](http://xe.com/fx) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: That's ~$800 yearly.

Answer (score 0):

**[NYSE Euronext](http://www.nyse.com/attachment/NYSE_EuroNext/index.html?sa_campaign=/microsite/exchangingworld/homepage-euro)** ([nyse.com](http://www.nyse.com/) / [euronext.com](http://www.euronext.com/)) is going to be your best option, but it isn't free.

As far as free options go, you'll always have a delay, 15 minutes is usually the most common.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FXstreet](http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/currency-rates/).

They seem to be real-time quotes. Euro/Eastern-European is available as a drop-down option.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see that you wanted a non-Java applet site. [Try this one.](http://forex.tradingcharts.com/quotes/euro_european_currency_unit.html)

Comment: Neither of the links you provided is showing an exhaustive list of currencies and their quotes. The last one is even more limited than the first in this regard...